# When I Try To Update My FDT, I See Errors. Why?

Tags: flash, fdt

See the attached image. Why are there so many errors? I want to update FDT but not sure how / why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Update**: [You could be having a problem with Java](http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/browse/FDT-2800).

***Update 2**: FDT 5.6 now has all the extra download sites disabled by default.

### Everything is fine. Those are errors associated with Eclipse, not FDT.

Notice in the attached screenshot how FDT updates have 'FDT' in the description. Only items with 'FDT" need to be updated.

[image]

If want to prevent all possible errors, not associated with FDT, then remove all update sites not associated with FDT 5 (fdt.powerflasher.com/update/fdt5).

*As others have pointed out, this will prevent all Eclipse updates, but that is ok. FDT is tested against a particular Eclipse version: the one it ships with & it's usually the latest.  If you did update your Eclipse, the stability of FDT cannot be guaranteed because you would then be on an untested version (of Eclipse).*

[image]

Comment: Umm, if you do what Alan suggests and remove the update sites, you may well bugger your chances of ever updating anything else in Eclipse ever again...
Just a hint :-)